# Keyboard not working

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, uefi

I have installed 64x 16.04 Ubuntu on my surface laptop recently however i am unable to use my keyboard since during the installation. However USB keyboard and mouse are functional. Surface uses a UEFI system, however i could not find any option that mentions keyboard or mouse in there.

to be accurate, my keyboard is not exactly disabled. I am able to swtich on/off backlights and my power button is working too which is integrated in the keyboard.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure you're booting in UEFI mode?

Comment: I don't if has any other boot mode in it